# How to set User-based form field choices in a django ModelForm (with django-allauth)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm using Django 1.8 and django-allauth. I have a simple form with a dropdown menu that allows my Users to choose a Character model.
I have a UserCharacter model that looks like this:

```
    class UserCharacter(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        character = models.ForeignKey(Character)
        is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In my main Form I'm only displaying the "character" field, which appears as a dropdown menu of Character objects. So far, so good - users can select a Character and it is saved as a UserCharacter association.

What I'm trying to do is display all Character objects that don't already have a UserCharacter linked to the currently logged in User. I would normally use the limit_choices_to feature, like so:

```
    character = models.ForeignKey(Character, limit_choices_to={'id__in': UserCharacter.objects.filter(user_id=[USER_ID]))
```

my problem is, I don't know how to get access to the current user object from the UserCharacter Model or from a ModelForm. I normally need access to the current request to get at the django-allauth logged in user object. normally in place of [USER_ID] is I would put

```
    self.request.user.id
```

to get the current user's id from django-allauth, but I can't do that from the Model here. How would I go about changing the form choices in the ModelForm based on the current user object?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this needs the currently logged in user then you have to do it in the `View` where you override the form characters `QuerySet` based on your user.

```
form.character.queryset = Character.objects.filter(....)
```

You can also pass the `request.user` to the form and do the filter there in the constructor.

Comment: Could you expand more on this answer? Which specific method(s) would you recommend overriding, from which View parent class(es), to accomplish this? Thanks.